# Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, http-post

I have this error when I run my client server JS application

CONSOLE ERROR IN DevTools:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/style.css' because its MIME type 
('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
console.log(data);
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
 // Body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
  body: JSON.stringify(data), 
});

  try {
    const newData = await response.json();
    console.log(newData);
    return newData;
  }catch(error) {
  console.log("error", error);
  }
 }

postData('/addMovie', {answer:42});
```

SERVER CODE:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('website'))

const port = 3000
app.listen(port, getServerPortInfo)
function getServerPortInfo() {
    console.log("Server listening at port " + port)
}

const data = []
app.post('/addMovie', addMovie)

function addMovie (req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log("here")
    data.push(req.body)
    console.log(data)
    res.send(data)

 }
```

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weather Journal</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,600,700|Ranga:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>    
    <div>
        <button id="generate" type = "submit"> Generate </button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please provide some links, advice, or pointers that would help direct me towards a solution?

The strange thing is that I do not have a css file.

Please note that I have already gone through this post and it has not helped my case:
[The console of Chrome error : Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968695/the-console-of-chrome-error-refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-tex)

Comment: Can you also check to see if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182092/mime-type-error-with-express-static-and-css-files) is relevant?  There, the css fetch actually results in a 404.  Did you check your in-browser developer tools (network tab) to see that the resource was actually fetched correctly?

Comment: wait...just did a double-take.  You said _The strange thing is that I do not have a css file._ But you are clearly linking to one with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`  So what's up with that?  If you know there is no css file, but you're trying to fetch one, then you should have known a 404 was coming.  Am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: That is a css from google though its not something local. There shouldnt be a problem with that, right?

Comment: No it's not.  That's a resource-relative path.  If you're hosting at `http://localhost:3000/` then `style.css` is `http://localhost:3000/style.css`. specifically **not** something that will be fetched from google.com  You would need to specify the *full url* of where the style.css resource is hosted.

Comment: Aaah thank you so much. That solved it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

But you do not have a *style.css* file.  The request for `http://localhost:3000/style.css` has resulted in a 404 error, and your server has served up an HTML response (mimetype is `text/html`).  The error says it all:

> Refused to apply style from '`http://localhost:3000/style.css`' because
> its MIME type  ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type,
> and strict MIME checking is enabled.

To correct the problem, either link to the actual *style.css* with a full URL, or remove the stylesheet link entirely if no such *style.css* resource exists anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to explicitly tell your express app to consider the folder as static to retain the mime type of the file.

Something like:

```
app.use(express.static("./"));
```