# SOLUTION: Error: “http://localhost:3000/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) using Express

Tags: express, mime, x-content-type-options

I'm learning Express and I had a problem with the stylesheet. The console was printing an error related to **X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff**. After a long search through MDN, I came to an efficient(simple and useful) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376129/20686127)   here on Stack Overflow given by Zahid.

> You would need to explicitly tell your express app to consider the folder as static to retain the mime type of the file.
>
> Something like:
>
> ```
> app.use(express.static("./"));
> ```

I hope it helps everyone who is starting out in this world, like me. ✌

Comment: Hello there and welcome to Stackoverflow.
This is not a question, please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: @MohammadHoseinBalkhani thanks...I know... I just wanted to make it easier to get the answer from google because it was hard for me to find it 

Comment: You can create a question and answer it yourself. Change the question to: 

How do you solve the following error: “http://localhost:3000/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) using Express?